# INET 3.99.3 examples running error in Omnet++ 5.3 of ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, omnet++, inet, ubuntu-18.04

After installing Omnet++ 5.3 in ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I imported INET 3.99.3 project folder and I was not able to build from IDE. Later I found an article and resolved building issues.

But now, I am facing an issue to run examples, are located in INET 3.99.3 project folder  as shown in below:

> Error: Cannot load library '../../../src//libINET.so':
>   ../../../src//libINET.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN3osg5GroupE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please refer to this issue to resolve your linking error.

There is a patch to solve the linking error

https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/issues/353